# jQuery show one hide all divs

Tags: jquery, html

Well after looking many post on SO, I am still not able to get where I'm going wrong. There is no change in my code. It still shows every data. I want data from `<div class="span9">` to hide upon selecting a link from `<div class="span3">`

Where I'm going wrong?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span9" id = "4_2">
      hello<br>
      How are you????
      2013-08-06 14:33:16
    </div> <!--end of div class span9 -->
    <div class="span3">      
         <a href="#" class = "dropdown-link">mithila</a>
    <div> <!--end of div span3-->

    <div class="span9" id = "1_1">
       My name is praful<br>
       2013-08-06 14:22:17
    </div> <!--end of div class span9 -->

     <div class="span3">
        <a href="#" class = "dropdown-link">mithila</a>
     </div> <!--end of div span3-->
</div><!--end of div row-->
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.row').each(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $div = $("div.span9", $dropdown);
      $div.toggle();
      $("div.span9").not($div).hide();
      return false;
    });

});

  $('html').click(function(){
    $("div.span9").hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: Showing us your JavaScript code would be a good start ;)

Comment: Is there some JQuery code that goes along with this...?

Comment: I forgot to include th jquery code. Question updated.

Comment: Well, I have edited my HTML code to more better and clean code now. Kindly look into the same now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.span9').hide();  // I put this here but best is to have it in CSS
    $(".span3").click(function () {
        $('.span9').hide();
        $(this).prev('.span9').show();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ctYzQ/3/)**

You don't need so much code. This code will hide/show the previous `.span9` to the clicked `.span3`.

I added `$('.span9').hide();` in the jQuery but better would be to have in CSS `.span9 {dislay:none;}` so they hide from the beginning.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Your code is correct but your current code hides the <div> upon re-clicking on the link again. I, rather want that when one link is clicked and data in the other<div> are hide automaticaaly.

Comment: @user1162512, If I understand right you look for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ctYzQ/2/

Comment: Yes.Somewhat like this. But initially all the data should be hide and then clicking upon the a specific link should fetch only its data and kept on hiding the other data.

Comment: @user1162512, great! glad I could help. Check my suggestion about having the function to hide them from begging on CSS, its better.

Comment: Sergio, one question. Why its a good practise to put `$('.span9').hide();` in css and how should I go abput it?

Comment: @user1162512, if you have it in jQuery it can happen that all `.span9` show up and then flash to hide when the code runs. The user might see a page with all `.span9` open before they hide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your Jquery code looks like, but maybe try something like this?

```
    $('.span3').on('click', 'a', function(){
        $('.span9').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Well, my jQuery code isnt correct for show/hide part. 

I have edited my HTML code to more better and clean code now. Kindly look into the same now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click handler, prevent the default link follow, hide the span9 div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.row').on('click', 'a.span3', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div.span9").hide();
    });
});
```

The rest of the code, delete?

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zsnp5/

Comment: Not working.
I replaced my jQuery code with yours, and its not working on the HTML that I edited 5 minutes ago. Please check whether you have posted your solution according to the HTML which is there currently. Thanks

Comment: I used the original markup, feel free to translate from that in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I did edited it according to my own needs, but it just shows/hide/toggles one field. I want that upon clicking one link, only one div shows up and rest all hides. currently it hides and shows everything. 
Any suggestions why?

Comment: That is another/different question altogether - clarify in the new question if you want the proceeding or subsequent element to hide based upon the link clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your HTML was wrong see a working example of the HTML and jQuery here:

http://jsfiddle.net/alutz33/KrgnT/1/

```
<div class="row">
<div id="4_2" class="span9">hello<br />How are you???? 2013-08-06 14:33:16</div>
<!--end of div class span9 -->
<div class="span3"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">mithila</a>

</div>
<!--end of div span3-->
<div class="span9" id="1_1">My name is praful
    <br>2013-08-06 14:22:17</div>
<!--end of div class span9 -->
<div class="span3"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">mithila</a>

</div>
<!--end of div span3-->
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.span3').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $(".span9").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Its still the same,as the problem I posted. This is no solution to the problem.

Comment: did you see the jsfiddle? there is jquery there, i'll also append it here.